# How to Create some basic controls like listbox on winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, listbox, codeblocks

Am doing a small project in cpp using codeblocks ide on my windows 8.1 machine. Adding the menu was fine and even I went as far as adding some common controls like button, static, edit based on some of my notes from online sources.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

#define BTN_BUTTON 201
#define CMB_COMBOBOX 202
#define LST_LISTBOX 203
#define TXT_TEXTBOX 204
/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "CodeBlocksWindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Code::Blocks Template Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow ("combobox", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
                20, 10, 400, 120,
                hwnd, (HMENU)CMB_COMBOBOX, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
  // If you uncomment the function below that I used to create a listbox see my program does not compile          
/*
                CreateWindow ("listbox", NULL,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_COMBOBOX,
                    20, 40, 140, 120,
                    hwnd, (HMENU)LST_LISTBOX, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
                */
            CreateWindow("edit", NULL,
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL| ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                170, 40, 250, 120,
                hwnd, (HMENU)TXT_TEXTBOX, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            CreateWindow("button", "Submit This",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                300, 170, 120, 30,
                hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_BUTTON, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now everything on my code works perfect if I omit the code for the listbox which i dearly want to be part of my code. In the function for creating ListBox the compile comments

> error:  "LBS_COMBOBOX" was not declared in this scope

yet it is okay with **LBS_NOTIFY**. I would appreciate if someone enlightened me on an issue prventing my cpp program from running. Am still a newbie in this and I could have overlooked on something.

This is the editted version

Comment: Why do you have standalone functions in a header file?

Comment: I have already explained I am just beginning sir

Comment: According to MSDN [List Box Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149(v=vs.85).aspx), `LBS_COMBOBOX` requires `#include <Winuser.h>`. I'm not sure whether it is still necessary in C++11 (and above) but I would remark functions with bodies in headers as `static inline`.

Comment: @Scheff `winuser.h` is included by `windows.h`, which you should be including instead. And both are in the question anyway.

Comment: Why are you setting `LBS_COMBOBOX` in the first place? And what development environment do you have?

Comment: In `main.cpp`: `WindowManager.h` is included after `windows.h` and `winuser.h`. Thus, if `main.cpp` is compiled the required definitions should be available in `WindowManager.h`. If `WindowManager.h` is included in another cpp file the required `windows.h` might be missing. I guess it's better to include `windows.h` in `WindowManager.h`.

Comment: Did you notice the predefined system classes mentioned in MSDN [CreateWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx)? I would prefer them (at least for the reason to let the compiler detect typos in case). I mean to use `LISTBOX` instead of `"listbox"`.

Comment: Why don't you use dialog box templates instead? You are wasting time by creating coding common controls from code.

Comment: I tried to compile your code (as is). There are undefined identifiers. I assume you use a resource file which is not provided. Could you, please, complete the exposed code (to make it an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Unrelated but you are setting hbrBackground incorrectly.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but using ANSI encoding in 2017 is a capital crime. Code:: Blocks must die, just for using it as a default.

Comment: am doing this to learn cpp and nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick one to help yoou create a listbox based on a tutorial on a link here http://winapi.foosyerdoos.org.uk/index.php

```
HWND CreateListbox(const HWND hParent,const HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD dwStyle, const RECT& rc,const int id,const ustring& caption)
{
    //dwStyle|=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL|LBS_NOSEL;
    dwStyle|=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL|LBS_NOTIFY;
    return CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("listbox"), 
        caption.c_str(), 
        dwStyle, 
        rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom,
        hParent, 
        reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(static_cast<INT_PTR>(id)), 
        hInst, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `LBS_COMBOBOX` anyway, it is a internal style used by Windows:

> The combo box itself must set this style. If the style is set by anything but the combo box, the list box will regard itself incorrectly as a child of a combo box and a failure will result.

Maybe your SDK does not include a define for this style because you should never be setting it.

Comment: Unless you wrote your own Windows.h you must have some sort of SDK. If you are compiling with MinGW/GCC then you are probably using their win32 headers ("w32api" is their name for it).

Answer (score 0):

check out this links for quite some good examples you are yearning for:

1. [Windows API tutorial for the C programming language](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/)
2. [FoosYerDoos ~ WinAPI Programming](http://winapi.foosyerdoos.org.uk/index.php)
3. [Relisoft Software - Windows Api Tutorial](http://www.relisoft.com/Win32/index.htm)
4. [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/)
5. [Win32 API Tutorials](http://www.alsprogrammingresource.com/win32.html)

If you go throught those tutorials you should be able to  get along quite well.